# Apache Mina Serial Error: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError

Tags: serial-port, mina

I've worked days on an serial connection with Apache Mina. But I've had no luck. I've built a little test program and got this error back:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.mina.core.session.AbstractIoSession.<init>(Lorg/apache/mina/core/service/IoService;)V
at org.apache.mina.transport.serial.SerialSessionImpl.<init>(SerialSessionImpl.java:73)
at org.apache.mina.transport.serial.SerialConnector.connect0(SerialConnector.java:97)
at org.apache.mina.core.service.AbstractIoConnector.connect(AbstractIoConnector.java:262)
at org.apache.mina.core.service.AbstractIoConnector.connect(AbstractIoConnector.java:172)
at org.apache.mina.timeserver.SerialTest.main(SerialTest.java:22)
```

I have no idea what I can do to solve this problem...

and here is my little **SerialTest.java**

```
package org.apache.mina.timeserver;
import org.apache.mina.transport.serial.*;

import org.apache.mina.core.service.IoHandlerAdapter;
import org.apache.mina.core.session.IoSession;
import org.apache.mina.core.future.ConnectFuture;
import org.apache.mina.filter.codec.textline.TextLineCodecFactory;
import org.apache.mina.filter.codec.ProtocolCodecFilter;

public class SerialTest extends IoHandlerAdapter {

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public static void main(String [] args){

    SerialConnector connector = new SerialConnector();      
    connector.getFilterChain().addLast("codec", new ProtocolCodecFilter(
            new TextLineCodecFactory()));
    connector.setHandler(new SerialTest());
    String comPort = "COM10";
    int bauds = 9600;
    ConnectFuture cf = connector.connect(
        new SerialAddress(comPort, bauds,   SerialAddress.DataBits.DATABITS_8,
            SerialAddress.StopBits.BITS_1, SerialAddress.Parity.NONE,
            SerialAddress.FlowControl.NONE));       

    cf.join();      
    String rawcmd = "";
    while (true){
        rawcmd = System.console().readLine().trim();
        if (rawcmd.equals("exit"))
            break;
        else if (rawcmd.equals(""))
            continue;
        /* IoBuffer.setUseDirectBuffer(false); 
        IoBuffer buf = IoBuffer.allocate(1024); */            
        cf.getSession().write(rawcmd + "\r");//cf.getSession().write(rawcmd + "\r\n"); also tested
    }
    //cf.getSession().getCloseFuture().awaitUninterruptibly();
    cf.getSession().close();
    connector.dispose();
}
public void sessionClosed(IoSession session) {     
    System.err.println("Total " + session.getReadBytes() + " byte(s)");
}
public void messageSent(IoSession session, Object message) {
    System.out.println("message has been sent: " + message);
}
public void messageReceived(IoSession session, Object message) {
    System.out.println("message received:[" + message + "]");
}   
}
```

Comment: i updatet to the last Stable Version of the Mina apache framework and to the lastet mina-transport-serial. Now, it runs good. THX

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated the framework to the last stable version, and the extra file for serial (mina-transport-serial) too.

Now it runs well. Thanks for your help.